# Add AdMob Ads to my app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am learning to develop Android app from online tutorials and I got lots of answers from "stackoverflow" and am very thankful to the website and it's users for their help.

This is my first question to this community/forum. However, I got lots of answers and tutorials on different websites for this question but no luck.

Simply, I want to add AdMob ads to my app. They must be appear in all pages/activities of the app.

Please see below mentioned codes for the app. If someone can provide codes including admob it would be great help!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="abc"
    tools:context="com.example.bhagdev.transparentbuttons10.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/j3"
    tools:ignore="NamespaceTypo">



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp"
    android:onClick="next1"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp"
        android:onClick="aarti"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp"
        android:onClick="Thal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button4"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button6"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button7"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button7"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button8"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button8"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
    android:text="@string/button9"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button9"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button10"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button11"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button11"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
    android:text="@string/button12"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button12"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button13"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button13"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button14"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button14"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:text="@string/button15"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />

    <!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not much publications regarding a very cool stuff from AdMob called

> nativeAdsExpress

... But this kind of ads are very easy to implement, more attractive, give more revenues and with a much more clear integration and integrity within your app. 
I strongly recommend you to use it, it's very simple to implement and as it name indicates, it's 'express'. 
Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-express):